# SSRS not using default parameter values

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have a report in which I did everything the same (with respect to parameters) as I always do, but for some reason when I preview the report in Data Tools, default values for SystemName parameter isnt used.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Default and Available values are both set to a query embedded in the related dataset and no setting is different than the other parameters.

Has anyone experienced this before? Does anyone know what can cause this?

Additional screenshots:

[Photos](http://postimg.org/gallery/knx3s460/)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the default values screen?

Comment: yeah will do right now.

Comment: Where did the screenshot go??? @D Stanley

Comment: Added more shots. @Dave.Gugg

Comment: Put `SystemName` in Label field for `Available Values` for System Name parameter.

Comment: I did that, didnt change anything

Comment: Have you used Systemname as a parameter before?  I'm wondering if it is a reserved word and that's causing problems.

Comment: Yes i have on 3 separate occasions in the past month

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding the dataset?

Comment: just tried it, didnt work either. this is so bizarre

Answer (score 1):

Found solution to my problem. The problem was my query in the dataset for the systemname parameter had blank entries. So I added a where clause to filter null and blank fields and problem was solved. I assume blank comes first when things are sorted so thats why i was geting a blank default value